# Return an object from an array with a Select component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'd like to return the entire object representation of an item in a list, however, when a selection is made and `handleChangeSelectAuto` is called the original value from `useState` is returned, and from there forward the previous selected value is always returned.

How can I select an item from a list and return all its associated data?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

interface AutoSelectorProps {}

const AutoSelector: React.FC<AutoSelectorProps> = () => {
  const [auto, setAuto] = useState({} as object);
  const [autoName, setAutoName] = useState('' as string);

  const [autoList, setAutoList] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Car',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Truck',
      color: 'blue'
    },
  ]);

  const handleChangeSelectAuto = async (value: string) => {
    const index = autoList.findIndex((item) => {
      return item.name === value;
    });

    setAutoName(value);
    setAuto(autoList[index]);

    console.log(auto);
    // 1st log: {}
    // 2nd log: object from previous selection
    // 3rd log: object from previous selection, etc.
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Select Auto</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={autoName}
          label="Auto"
          onChange={(e) => handleChangeSelectAuto(e.target.value as string)}
        >
          {autoList.map((item) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={item.name} value={item.name}>
                {item.name}
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AutoSelector;
```

P.S. If I add a button and handler to log `auto` it will return the correct value, but I'm not seeing a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState is asynchronous. It will not show the values immediately. use `useEffect` to see the updated values

```
useEffect(() => {
       console.log(auto);


}, [auto])
```